# Using Excel's Cameral Tool with tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I use Camera tool with a table to create a dynamic picture?
I use advanced filter to filter a table.
I then convert the extract range into a table.
I select the entire extract table, Header and all of the rows.
Next I click the camera tool.
The cursor is a plus sign (+). I click on a tab of an adjacent worksheet.
The cursor is still a plus sign and I click where I want the picture.
The address bar show the address of the extract table (=Filter!$P$4:$U$25)
When I try to change the address to =ZoomResults (Refers to: =tbl_ZooominDetail[#Alll]) I get Reference isn't Valid
If I leave the address as (=Filter!$P$4:$U$25) then
When I run the advanced filter again, with different criteria, the picture is updated but there are blank rows
The last row with data has a little triangle indicating it is the last row of the table.
Why do I have extra rows?

Comment: try: `=indirect("tbl_ZooominDetail[#All]")`

Comment: Well that's interesting. I didn't know you could do that. But......I need an image that I can float over my data. I figured out if you create the range before you create table and then name that range you can use that range name to refer to the source of camera data.

Comment: you would put that in the Refers To:

Comment: ??? I don't understand where is the Refers to: